# Need help understanding "Set-ADUser" in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to update job titles in Active Directory from a CSV file that contains email addresses and job titles, but I'm running into a problem because the CSV file doesn't contain the user's "-Identity", only their email address.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Folder\JobTitles.csv" 

ForEach ($item In $csv) 
{ 
   Set-ADUser -EmailAddress $item.Email -Title $item.Title
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that when I run this command, it prompts me to enter the Identity for each user.  I understand I should really be using this instead:

```
Set-ADUser -Identity $item.SamAccountName -Title $item.Title
```

But there's an issue with this.  In our AD, half of the employees "User logon name (pre-Windows 2000)" use the format "first initial last name" and half use "first name.last name".  From what I saw from testing, this is the field that -Identity is pulling from/looking for, but that information isn't part of my CSV file.

My question is, is there a way to get the "Set-ADUser" to work using just the email address as the unique user identifier/identity?

Thank you!
Nick

Comment: Use `Get-ADUser -Filter "mail -eq '$item.Email'"` to find the user. Then pipe the found instance through to Set-ADUser. However... If your CSV only contains the _desired_ email address you will need some other unique property that you do have in your CSV file to identify the user

Comment: foreach ($row in $csvData) {
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter {UserPrincipalName -eq $row.Email}
    Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Title $row.JobTitle
}  Can you try this, Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. There’s an inefficient way of using the email account name to get the user object using [`Get-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps), and then modifying the object with [`Set-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps):

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Folder\JobTitles.csv"

ForEach ($item In $csv) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter 'EmailAddress -like "$item.Email"' | Set-ADUser -Title $item.Title
}
```

I say “Inefficient” because `-Filter`ing isn’t really performant - but it works if the user object already has the email address set.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I tried your suggestion, and while it ran with no errors, it also didn't change the Title name for my test subject in AD.  I think there may be a problem with this portion of the command:  -Filter 'EmailAddress -like "$item.Email"'

Comment: When I tried it on my system, it worked; make sure that the `Get-ADUser` command is working (i.e., actually getting a user) before passing the object to `Set-ADUser`.

Comment: Yes, the get-aduser command is working by itself.  I'm working remotely today, I will try this all again on Monday when I'm back in the office.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @carproblems Two quote mistakes in the code above. Try this: `"EmailAddress -like '$($item.Email)'"`

Comment: Well, I'm stumped.  I'm back in the office and the script runs without any errors or notifications, but it isn't changing anything in AD.  It does show the "progress bar", so it's running, but no change is made.  I went back to my original script, and it does still work and I see the "progress bar".

Comment: @DavidTrevor - I don't think the order of quotes matters, but the `$()` construct doesn't seem to be needed - at least not on my system. I don't think it will hurt, however.

Comment: A string in Powershell enclosed by single quotes `'` cannot access variables as the `$` character will be interpreted as a literal, so I don't see how this would work? @JeffZeitlin

Comment: @DavidTrevor - I won't swear to anything other than that it works on my system, but the rules may be slightly different with respect to the `-Filter` parameter on AD and WMI/CIM cmdlets.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin ran some tests again, your quoting does not work for me both in PS5 and PS7. Tested with `Get-ADUser` and `-Filter` parameter. Care to share a reproducible minimal example that works for you?

Answer (score 0):

`mail` is not unique attribute in AD, so you should use it with care.

```
foreach ($item in $importedItems) {
    $emailAddress = $item.emailAddress
    $newTitle = $item.Title
    try {
        $users = @( Get-ADUser -Filter "(mail -eq '$($emailAddress)')" -Properties @('title', 'mail') -ErrorAction Stop )
        
        if ($users.Count -gt 1) {
            throw "email is not unique!"
        }
        
        if ($users.Count -eq 0) {
            throw "email was not found!"
        }

        $user = $users[0]

        if ($user.Title -eq $newTitle) {
            Write-Warning "User $($user.mail) already have title `"$($user.Title)`". Skipping"
            continue
        }

        Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Title $newTitle -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction Stop
    } catch {
        Write-Warning "$($emailAddress): $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}
```

Comment: I've read that before, but I don't grasp how or why that's possible.  Could you please explain why it's not a unique attribute?  At least in our environment, I know that no email address has ever been shared by two users.

Comment: Because you *can* create 2 users with same value in `mail` attribute in Active Directory, and when changing email it is not getting checked against correctness nor uniqueness. This is enough to not be sure

Comment: Reasons are different.  For example, you have 2 users in 2 different OUs in your AD with same email but different passwords - one is your main mailbox-enabled user goes for Azure AD, exchange, etc.., and second is for authenticating in /VeryImportantSystemWithLimitedAccess/ which is configured to look users against /UsersForVeryImportantSystem/ OU.

Or just inattention as it usually happens.

Comment: Additional question, should the second one of these qualifiers be -lt instead of -gt?  if ($users.Count -gt 1) {
            throw "email is not unique!"
        }
        
        if ($users.Count -gt 1) {
            throw "email was not found!"

Comment: fixed this @carproblems , updated.

Comment: @carproblems and also added `mail` property in `Get-ADUser`

Comment: Thank you!  I ran your script and it didn't return any errors, but it also didn't appear to make the change in AD for my test user, which is what happened when I ran the script below.  I'm working remotely today, I will have to try again on Monday when I'm back in the office.

Comment: Well, I'm stumped.  I'm back in the office and the script runs without any errors or notifications, but it isn't changing anything in AD and I don't see the "progress bar".  I went back to my original script, and it does still work and I see the "progress bar".